# Display a proper error to user

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, adderror

may I know how to make the system show error to users in a proper way? Because I try to use adderror(), but still not working. it keeps showing the below error if the user does not fills in these fields, Currency_Rate_MYR__c, Currency_Rate__c, Currency_Rate_EURO__c. I don't want to make these fields required. Just let the system show error in a proper way

```
Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger Pulling caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Pulling: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.: Trigger.Pulling: line 37, column 1
```

here is the trigger code

```
trigger Pulling on Payment__c (before Insert, before update) {
    double myRinggit = 0;
    double CNYSing = 0;
    double EURODollar = 0;
    
    set<Id> lstId = new set<Id>();
    for(Payment__c ob:trigger.new){
        if(ob.Name_of_Customer__c != null){
            lstId.add(ob.Name_of_Customer__c);
        }
    }
    list<Order__c> lstOb1 =[select Id,Requested_Delivery_Date__c, account__c, Account_SO_No__c,Po_No__c,Total_Qty_Pcs__c,Total_Amount_USD__c,Currency__c from Order__c where Account__c IN :lstId AND Status__c = 'Good' order by CreatedDate ];
    
    for(Payment__c ob2: trigger.new){
        ob2.Fetch_Data__c = '';
        ob2.Grant_Total__c = 0;
        for(integer i=0; i<lstOb1.size(); i++){
            ob2.Fetch_Data__c += ' Request Delivery Date ' + lstOb1[i].Requested_Delivery_Date__c+ ' Account/ SO No.: ' + lstOb1[i].Account_SO_No__c+' Po. No: '+lstOb1[i].Po_No__c+' Total Quantity.pcs: '+lstOb1[i].Total_Qty_Pcs__c+' Total Amount. usd: '+lstOb1[i].Total_Amount_USD__c+ '<Br/>';
            ob2.Grant_Total__c = ob2.Grant_Total__c + lstOb1[i].Total_Amount_USD__c;
            
            if(lstOb1[i].Currency__c == 'MYR'){
                myRinggit = myRinggit + lstOb1[i].Total_Amount_USD__c;
                ob2.MYR__c = myRinggit * ob2.Currency_Rate_MYR__c;
                if(ob2.Currency_Rate_MYR__c == 0){
                    ob2.addError('This SO have MYR currency');
                }
            }
            if(lstOb1[i].Currency__c == 'CNY'){
                CNYSing = CNYSing + lstOb1[i].Total_Amount_USD__c;
                ob2.CNY__C = CNYSing * ob2.Currency_Rate__c;
                if(ob2.Currency_Rate__c == 0){
                    ob2.addError('This SO have CNY currency');
                }
            }
            if(lstOb1[i].Currency__c == 'EURO'){
                EURODollar = EURODollar + lstOb1[i].Total_Amount_USD__c;
                ob2.EURO__c = EURODollar * ob2.Currency_Rate_EURO__c;
                if(ob2.Currency_Rate_EURO__c == 0){
                    ob2.addError('This SO have EURO currency');
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help. Let me know if you need further clarification Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error you are receiving is not related to the `addError()` methods you are using.
Probably on this line

```
ob2.EURO__c = EURODollar * ob2.Currency_Rate_EURO__c;
```

you have `ob2.Currency_Rate_EURO__c` which is null. And this null is then evaluated in the `*` operation which is causing this error.

And if you want to display this message to user in readable form you would need wrap this block in `try/catch` and then in catch block use the addError like this `.addError('Currency_Rate_EURO need to fill in as there is amount in euro')`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But may I know how to display this error to the user in a proper way? Because if the error is displayed like this, the user might not know what is the issue. I think it is good if we can pop up an error like 'Currency_Rate_EURO need to fill in as there is amount in euro'

Comment: i've edited my answer